# Como mapear o xdebug no VSCode para um vhost?

Tags: php, virtualhost, xdebug

Tenho um projeto que está vindo do SD Card:

```
/Volumes/SDCARD/sd_projects/sistema-news/sistema-news-web/
```

O XDebug funciona quando tenho uma arquivo na raiz do diretório do localhost: `/Applications/Ampps/www/`, mas **não** no meu projeto que é um virtualhost:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    <Directory "/Volumes/SDCARD/sd_projects/sistema-news/sistema-news-web">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
    </Directory>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@gutennews.local
       DocumentRoot "/Volumes/SDCARD/sd_projects/sistema-news/sistema-news-web"

       ServerName local.system.com.br  
       ServerAlias www.local.system.local
       php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data -1
       setEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /Volumes/SDCARD/sd_projects/sistema-news/sistema-news-web/sistema.com.br.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /Volumes/SDCARD/sd_projects/sistema-news/sistema-news-web/sistema.com.br.key

        DocumentRoot "/Volumes/SDCARD/sd_projects/sistema-news/sistema-news-web"
        ErrorLog "/Applications/Ampps/apache/logs/https.local.sistema.com.br.err"
        CustomLog "/Applications/Ampps/apache/logs/https.local.sistema.com.br.log" combined
  
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

O Xdebug está habilitado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No php.ini tenho isso:

```
;Debug
[XDebug] 
zend_extension=/usr/local/php/extensions/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/Applications/AMPPS/tmp 
xdebug.idekey="vscode_xdebug"
```

Mas quando eu marco a bolinha vermelha na linha (breakpoint), e bato na página que chama esse método, nada está acontecendo. Era pra me jogar para o vscode de volta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a configuração do listen no vscode (launch.json), com o plugin PHP Debug (Felix Becker):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

**Detalhes adicionais:** A versão do php é 7.3.11, o xdebug é 2.9.6 (para MAC)

[Exemplo que não consegui aplicar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug).

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido o mapeamento:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        }
       
    ],
    "pathMappings": {
        "/Volumes/SDCARD/sd_projects/": "https://local.gutennews.com.br:8810/"
      }

}
```